# View.OnClickListener не видит таба по кнопке

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, android-on-click, onclicklistener

Метод `onClick` внутри фрагмента `class ExchangeRateFragment : Fragment(), View.OnClickListener {`

```
 override fun onClick(view: View) {
        when(view.id) {
    
            R.id.sort -> {
                exchangeRateViewModel?.getSortCurrencyAlphabetAscending()
                loadExchangeRate()
            }
        }
    }
```

`layout` фрагмента

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".presentation.ExchangeRateFragment">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/baseCurrency"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:text="@string/base"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                tools:ignore="MissingConstraints,RtlHardcoded,RtlSymmetry,SpUsage" />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:id="@+id/sort"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                android:layout_marginTop = "30dp"
                android:padding="20dp"
                android:background="@color/black"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:text="@string/sort" />

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/exchangeRateRV"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/baseCurrency"/>

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </FrameLayout>

</layout>
```

Проводил дебаг, приложение просто не видит нажатия по кнопке

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галку слева от него

Answer (score 0):

А как вы хотели вызывать этот метод? У вас нет привязки к кнопке. Попробуйте передавать в макет ViewModel и вызывать метод оттуда:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com.n8ebel.databindingsandbox.MainViewModel" />

    </data>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        >
...

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Click Me"
            android:onClick="@{() -> viewModel.handleClick()}"
            />

    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

вот например, и дальше при инициализации нужно пробросить ViewModel:

```
val binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView<ActivityMainBinding>(this, R.layout.activity_main).bindData {
            viewModel = MainViewModel("hello", 5, this@MainActivity)
        }
```

либо сделать через метод так как вы хотели:

```
android:onClick="testClick"
```

и метод сделать под это дело. У вас по факту сейчас судя по всему просто есть отдельно стоящий метод в фрагменте, и отдельно кнопка.

Comment: не очень понимаю, а разве `R.id.sort` это не обращение к кнопке из метода?

Comment: А с чего вы решили что этот метод у вас используется? Даже в доках не говорят например использовать какие-то дополнительные наследования https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/components/button